# Tkinter Canvas Text adding Border (outline)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having trouble to add borders (outline) in Tkinter Canvas Text, like this:

[image: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC147277.jpg]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC147277.jpg))</sub>

but:

```
self.text1 = self.canvasFrame.create_text(100, 100, text = "Hello",
    font = NORMAL_FONT, fill = BLUE_COLOR, borderwidth = 2)


File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2321, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-borderwidth"
```

and I tried "bd = 2" too...

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2321, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bd"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The canvas text object doesn't have a borderwith attribute, i don't think it's possible in Tkinter. Please see a reference here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_text.html

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do what you want. The text items of the canvas don't support a borderwidth option, or any other option that would give you the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but you can create something like this:

```
from tkinter import Canvas


class NewCanvas(Canvas):
    def create_border_text(self, text="Under developing", borderwidth=None, bordercolor=None, **kw):
            textid = self.create_text(self.winfo_reqwidth() // 2, self.winfo_reqheight() // 2, text=text)
    horizontal_offset, vertical_offset = 40, 40
    bbox = self.bbox(textid)
    new_bbox = (bbox[0] - horizontal_offset // 2, bbox[1] - vertical_offset // 2,
                bbox[2] + horizontal_offset // 2, bbox[3] + vertical_offset // 2)

    self.create_rectangle(*new_bbox, width=borderwidth, outline=bordercolor)
    self.tag_raise(textid)
```